# insert or replace statement not working with sqlite3 and python

Tags: python, sqlite

Everytime I run this through the python interpreter it writes new values.  for example:

```
name = ben
age = 10
phone = 42045042
```

If I run it 10 times.  I get 10 duplicates in my database.  I know it has to be an easy fix, but I've been working on this for hours and can't figure it out.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('addressbook.db')
cur=conn.cursor()
conn.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people(name TEXT,
                       age TEXT, phone TEXT, fblink TEXT)''')
conn.execute("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO people values (?, ?, ?, ?)", ben.displayPerson())
cursor = conn.execute("SELECT name, age, phone, fblink from people")
for row in cursor:
   print "NAME = ", row[0]
   print "AGE = ", row[1]
   print "PHONE = ", row[2]
   print "FACEBOOK LINK = ", row[3], "\n"
cur.close()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Why are you using `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ...`? Shouldn't it be just `INSERT INTO`?

Comment: insert into gives me the same problem, that's why i tried insert or replace.

Answer (score 2):

There's no primary key field.

Make a primary key field.

For example:

```
conn.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people(name TEXT primary key,
                       age TEXT, phone TEXT, fblink TEXT)''')
```

`REPLACE` is executed when UNIQUE constraint violation occurs. Without primary key (or unique ..), it does not happen.

Comment: it has the conn.commit

Comment: @user2905382, I misunderstood your question. I updated the answer.

Comment: i have no idea what a primary key does, but i will try this.  also i reworded my question

Comment: I don't know why or how, but that fixed it.  You are a genius!

Comment: @user2905382, Primary key is like the identifier of the row.

Comment: @user2905382, `REPLACE` is executed when UNIQUE constraint violation occurs. Without primary key (or unique ..), it does not happen.

Answer (score 1):

Your table has no primary key, and hence SQLite doesn't know what it should "OR REPLACE" since it has nothing to base replacing on. Add a primary key.

Comment: A primary key is just one of the methods to get a UNIQUE constraint.